# Two subspaces of different dimensions and the orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I need help getting started with this problem. Please just give me a nudge in the right direction.

> Suppose $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of the Euclidean space $V$ such that $\dim(U_1) < \dim(U_2)$.
> Show that there is a nonzero vector $u \in U_2$ such that $u$ is in the orthogonal complement of $U_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U_1^\perp \cap U_2 = \{0\}$ then
$$
\dim(V)
\ge \dim(U_1^\perp) + \dim(U_2)
= \dim(V) - \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2)
> \dim(V)
$$ by the hypothesis $\dim(U_1) < \dim(U_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nudge: this can be proved easily using the codimension inequality:
$$\mathop{\mathrm{codim}}(U_1^{\perp}\cap U_2)\le\mathop{\mathrm{codim}}(U_1^{\perp})+\mathop{\mathrm{codim}}(U_2)$$